# Select nearest 3D point with sfcgal

Tags: postgis, 3d, sfcgal

**The Data**

Two sets of 1000 points A.geom and B.geom in PostGIS

**The Problem**

1. From Set A take the first point and find its nearest neighbour in Set B
2. Calculate the 3D distance between these two points
3. Save the result to the dist column of Set A

I've been testing out various python libraries, I thought I had it working in shapely just to discover it ignores the z-dimension.

I think SFCGAL is the way to go, but I am inexperienced, is this a simple query, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It looks like I will need the ST_3DDistance()

Comment: I'm also looking into numpy

Comment: The answer given by @ThingumaBob to your question yesterday, using a LATERAL JOIN with the <<->> operator should also do the trick here. You just set LIMIT 1 in each lateral query, so you get the nearest point to every other point.

Comment: Thanks, I'll return to that solution, I'm circling a bit with this one.

Comment: You don't need SFCgal. There is also native PostGIS functions for ST_3DDistance and other distance related functions.